# Difference between && and -a in BASH

Tags: bash, unix, posix

From what I know, `&&` and `-a` both provide the conditional `AND` function in an expression for a BASH shell.

Is there any difference between the 2 of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `-a` and `-o` are [deprecated by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/test.html#tag_04_140_16). They can break depending on your input and should therefor not be used.

Comment: There are other differences, related to shell syntax, not POSIX suppport

Comment: @jimmcnamara The OP stated they know about both, so I think it can be safely assumed that the *syntactical* differences are known. Also, the linked document clearly shows the differences in syntax and otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Some differences:

AND/OR lists  for && but not -a:

```
false && echo foo || echo bar
true || echo foo && echo bar
[ -d directory ] || mkdir directory
```

-a is mor limited, as part of the test command:  either with test or inside [[,

```
test -d mydir -a -f somefile
[  -d mydir -a -f somefile  ]
```

-a and -o are also part of the find command syntax

Comment: The double bracket notation `[[` does not understand `-a` and `-o`, only `[` does.

Comment: Conversely,  [ -f t.lis &&  -f t.dat ] generates a syntax error.